# spring boot upload file with the other parameter by using @RequestPart cause Excption

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

when using spring boot upload file with parameter, I used @RequestPart for all parameter.
Here the code:

> spring boot: 2.7.8

when one of them is `String` and the other is `Integer` and both of them annotated by @RequestPart will be cause Exception

```java
package com.interfaces.anti.mage.api;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.interfaces.anti.mage.model.Address;
import com.interfaces.anti.mage.model.Order;
import com.interfaces.anti.mage.service.OrderService;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author dengbojing
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderApi {

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String upload(@RequestPart("file")MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("id") String id, @RequestPart("number") Integer number) {
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(number);
        return "success";

    }
}
```

Exception info:

```
2023-02-13 22:51:40,319 WARN  [http-nio-8099-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported]
```

when all the other parameter type is `String` and annotated by @RequestPart, the method will be worked and print the info.

```java
 @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String upload(@RequestPart("file")MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("id") String id, @RequestPart("number") String number) {
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(number);
        return "success";

    }
```

So why this? the exception means the program treat the `String` and `Integer` paramter as `Stream`? but why all `String` will be fine?
ps: even change to this `@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})` also got the same problem

ps: this is the request info:

[image: Here is the request]

Comment: There is no extra configuration, just only one `Controller`

Comment: What is the type of the parameters you are submitting? Each part has its own content-type, if that isn't compatible with the type you are trying to convert to it will fail. You are probably submitting things with a wrong content-type. A stream can be read directly into a `String` but not into an `Integer` (spring doesn't have a converter for that). So basically without knowing what and how you are sending things to this controller this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, I did not set for each parameter, just set a form-data for the request, but how to set content-type for each parameter.  I just understand how to set the request content-type by code.

Comment: You are sending it as text (that is the type you selected) you should specify it as a number which should create a better/proper type for the field.

Answer (score 1):

I take the chance of this post because it pointed me to the right direction anyway so, for sake of anyone using **Postman**, receiving the error above here is my hint, learnt with pain and solved thanks to the hints above.

In **Postman**, when you fill a **form-data** body, the table misses, by default I believe, the **CONTENT TYPE** column.
You can add the column the using the button on the right side, but then it will show *Auto* consequently, depending from your parameters, you should change it to the proper type.

[image]

I hope it may help others :)
Regards